# how to review a complete process/application activity?

Tags: process

In Ubuntu is it possible to check for an application/process  activity ? I want information like

- When the application/process started
- what files has been accessed by the application/process
- what I/O operations it have performed
- If application/process connected to Internet , with what IP's its communicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a tool named as Health check tool.

Health-check can monitor:

- CPU utilisation
- Wakeup events
- Context Switches
- File I/O operations (Open/Read/Write/Close using fnotify)
- System calls (using ptrace)
- Analysis of polling system calls
- Memory utilisation (including memory growth)
- Network connections
- Wakelock activity

To install it open your terminal and type as

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colin-king/white
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install health-check
```

[For information of what It can do please click here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/health-check-a-tool-to-diagnose-resource-usage.html)