# How can I see the I/O activity of certain programs?

Tags: 15.04

I only found a tool called "Health Check", but it's a bit old and since I am using the newest Ubuntu version, I am not sure if it tells me the correct data.

Also I only need to see the I/O activity, not a bunch of other data:

[how to review a complete process/application activity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348368/how-to-review-a-complete-process-application-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a summery of a certain process, you can use `iotop` with this syntax:

`sudo iotop -p PID`

PID is the pid of the process you're trying to analyze. you can get PID by using `top` or `ps -A` and search through it to find your process ID.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about this little program.

Comment: `iotop -o` does precisely that what I was looking for